# Android Check CheckBox From List In RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to check some checkbox with a recieved list from a Rest Service.

Here some code.

**REQUEST**

```
private void requestOpcionais() {
    OpcionalRequestHelper.opcionaisRequest(Request.Method.GET, EndpointURL.GET_OPCIONAIS, null, new Response.Listener<Opcional[]>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Opcional[] response) {
            ArrayList<Opcional> opcionalArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

            opcionalArrayList.addAll(Arrays.asList(response));

            mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            listOpcionalAdapter = new ListOpcionalAdapter(getActivity(), opcionalArrayList, VeiculoFragment.this);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(listOpcionalAdapter);

            if (veiculo != null) {
                setOpcionalVeiculoSelected(opcionalArrayList, veiculo.getOpcionais());
            }
            progressDialogOpcionais.dismiss();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            progressDialogOpcionais.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Erro ao carregar opcionais.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

There is the verification if my opcional list...

```
    private void setOpcionalVeiculoSelected(ArrayList<Opcional> opcionalArrayList, List<Opcional> opcionais) {
    for (Opcional opcionalList : opcionalArrayList) {
        for (Opcional opcionalVeiculo : opcionais) {
            if (opcionalVeiculo.getId() == opcionalList.getId()) {
                mOpcionalChecked.add(opcionalVeiculo);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How i check those "opcionais" on my recyclerview?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue on this way...

I've sended the array to my adapter.

```
if (veiculo != null) {
                setOpcionalVeiculoSelected(opcionalArrayList, veiculo.getOpcionais());
                listOpcionalAdapter = new ListOpcionalAdapter(getActivity(), opcionalArrayList, VeiculoFragment.this, veiculo.getOpcionais());
            } else {
                listOpcionalAdapter = new ListOpcionalAdapter(getActivity(), opcionalArrayList, VeiculoFragment.this, null);
            }
```

On my onBindViewHolder() I checked if my array is not null.

```
onBindViewHolder()    
if (opcionalsVeiculo != null) {
    setOpcionalVeiculoSelected(holder, position);
}
```

And finally check my array and the position of my other array from adapter.

```
private void setOpcionalVeiculoSelected(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    for (Opcional opcional : opcionalsVeiculo) {
        if (opcionals.get(position).getId() == opcional.getId()) {
            holder.chb_opcional.setChecked(true);
        }
    }
}
```